# Is it possible to give permission to a user via sudo for only a specific Bash script?

Tags: permissions, users

I'm an administrator of my Ubuntu 16.04.3.

On this system, there are many users, who are in the list of sudoers. I'm thinking if I can make such a configuration as below:

I'd like to create a Bash script for each user, each user can do nothing but execute this script.

In a word, each user can tell me what they want to do, and I'll put it into a Bash script. When they login, they can do nothing but execute this script.

Comment: Yes. see `man sudo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Initial setups

You can setup a script like so:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/user1.bash
#!/bin/bash

whoami
```

And add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d` like so:

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/users
user1            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/user1.bash
user2            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/user2.bash
user3            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/user3.bash
```

#### Example run

Now when we login as `user1`:

```
$ su - user1
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on centos7:
    always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION
    LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User user1 may run the following commands on centos7:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/user1.bash
```

We can see that this user is only allowed the 1 command `user1.bash`. If we run it. we can see that this user is able to run the script:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/user1.bash
root
```

But cannot run anything else:

```
$ sudo whoami
[sudo] password for user1:
Sorry, user user1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/whoami' as root on centos7.
```

#### References

- [Take Control of your Linux | sudoers file: How to with Examples](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)
- [Using sudo](https://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html)